# Any way to trick std::transform into operating on the iterator themselves?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

So I wrote this code which won't compile. I think the reason is because `std::transform`, when given an iterator range such as this will operate on the type pointed to by the iterator, not the iterator itself. Is there any simple wrapper, standard lib tool, etc. to make this code work i.e. to store all the iterators of the original map into a new vector, with minimum changes required? Thanks!

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using MT = std::multimap<char, int>;
using MTI = MT::iterator;

int main()
{
    MT m;
    m.emplace('a', 1); m.emplace('a', 2); m.emplace('a', 3);
    m.emplace('b', 101);
        
    std::vector<MTI> itrs;
    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(itrs), [](MTI itr){
        return itr;
    });
}
```

EDIT 1: Failed to compile with gcc11 and clang13, C++17/20

EDIT 2: The purpose of the question is mostly out of curiosity. I want to see what's a good way to manipulate existing standard algorithm to work on the level that I want. The sample code and problem are entirely made up for demonstration but they are not related to any real problem that requires a solution

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the original and underlying problem (if any, plain curiosity is also okay, but then please state it in the question itself)? Right now this feels very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Storing iterators for later use is almost always a mistake. They are intended to be transient.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for that comment, I'll make it clearer in the question

Comment: @molbdnilo ***Re: Storing iterators for later use is almost always a mistake***. Source? From the standard: *"Iterators are a generalization of pointers"* and I don't see any evidence that iterators are invalidated unless the underlying collection changes or its lifetime ends (and even then specific guarantees seem to be made, depending on the collection). Only the output iterator's write operation (`*r = o`) seems to cause invalidation (and that of course changes the collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there such a wrapper? Not in the standard. But it doesn't mean you can't write one, even fairly simply.

```
template<typename It>
struct PassIt : It {
    It& operator*()              { return *this; }
    It const& operator*() const  { return *this; }
    PassIt & operator++()        { ++static_cast<It&>(*this); return *this; }
    PassIt operator++(int) const { return PassIt{static_cast<It&>(*this)++}; }
};

template<typename It>
PassIt(It) -> PassIt<It>;
```

That is just an example<sup>1</sup> of wrapper that is a iterator of the specified template parameter type. It delegates to its base for the bookkeeping, while ensuring the the return types conform to returning the wrapped iterator itself when dereferencing.

You can use it in your example to simply copy the iterators

```
std::copy(PassIt{m.begin()}, PassIt{m.end()}, std::back_inserter(itrs));
```

[See it live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ynuUH09wHZQ4h19f)

---

(1) - It relies on `std::iterator_traits` deducing the correct things. As written in this example, it may not conform to all the requirements of the prescribed iterator type (in this case, we aimed at a forward iterator). If that happens, more boiler-plate will be required.

Comment: thank you, exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for. Appreciate the full template demo as well

Comment: Hi, the *Live* link broken. and I don't know how to follow through. The following code is not working.  https://godbolt.org/z/cTxs8MhzT  would you mind share the full code.

Comment: @Mark - Broken how? It takes me to the example and spits out the expected output bellow it. And your example isn't working because you try and insert iterators into a vector of integers. Compare your code to the OP.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I guess the website is down. Anyway, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass to `std::transform` and algorithms in general are supposed to use elements not iterators. You could use the key to find the iterator in the map, though thats neither efficient nor simple. Instead use a plain loop:

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) itrs.push_back(it);
```